# inserting into database in java with prepareStatement

Tags: java, prepared-statement, derby

my program always stops at inserting into DB table without crashing. Here is my code

creating DataSource and connection:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    manager = new IngredientManager();
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:derby:memory:ingredient;create=true");       
    manager.setDataSource(ds);
    manager.createTables();
}
```

method createTables():

```
public void createTables() throws ServiceFailureException, SQLException {
   Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
   con.setAutoCommit(false);
   String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE INGREDIENTS("
           + "ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, "
           + "NAME VARCHAR(255), "
           + "AMOUNT DOUBLE, "
           + "UNIT VARCHAR(255), "
           + "RECIPEID INTEGER NOT NULL "
           + ")";

   PreparedStatement query = con.prepareStatement(createTableSQL);
   query.executeUpdate();
}
```

this everything works fine but when program comes to this:

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
query = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO INGREDIENTS (NAME, AMOUNT, UNIT, RECIPEID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

after connection.prepareStatement program doesnt do anything else, just building forever. Any ideas why this could be corrupted? thanks

Comment: What do you mean with _building forever_ ?? How do you verify that the following code is never executed?

Comment: I have breakpoint on method query = connection.prepareStatement(..) and breakpoint on method after this one and program will never come to the second breakpoint

Comment: Remove the first breakpoint. Will the other one be reached now?

Comment: connection.setAutoCommit(false); - will reach
query = connection.prepareStatement(...); - will reach
anotherMethod(); - will not reach

Comment: Try calling `con.commit();` at the end of `createTables()`.

Comment: Yes, on most DBMS DDL has to be in their own transaction. If you set autocommit to false, the INSERT prepare statement will wait (seemingly forever) for the CREATE TABLE DDL to commit

Comment: gogognome you're right, make propper comment so i can commit you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `createTables()` creates a connection (and transaction) to the database.
The code that hangs creates a second connection (and transaction). The second transaction is blocked until the first transaction gets commited, since they both lock on the same table.

Calling `con.commit();` at the end of `createTables()` should fix the problem.